# Using a port for both input and output

Tags: assembly, intel, 8051

I have started learning `Intel's 8051` assembly programming. I wrote a a test calculator program. I am using only 3 ports out of four. I am wondering if I can use a port for both input and output in the same program.

For Example, in this program Port 3 is used for taking a flag bit as input and also to display output.

Here is some of the code:

```
 JB P3.4, DisplayResult

 DisplayResult:

 MOV P3, #00H
 MOV P3, R0

 Here:

 SJMP Here
```

Regards

Comment: Google "8051 configure ports".  All three top hits are good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. you can.

Try to understand why the `MOV P3, #00H` was written. 
If you want pin 0 of P3 to be O and pin 1 of P3 to be I so you would write `MOV P3, # 00000010B` and so on.